# Extracting Spark logs (Spark UI contents) from Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to save Apache Spark logs (the contents of Spark UI), not necessarily stderr, stdout and log4j files (although they might be useful too) to a file so that I can send it over to someone else to analyze.

I am following the manual described in the Apache Spark documentation here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact

The problem is that I am running the code on Azure Databricks. Databricks saves the logs elsewhere and you can display them from the web UI but cannot export it.
When I ran the Spark job with spark.eventLog.dir set to a location in DBFS, the file was created but it was empty.

Is there a way to export the full Databricks job log so that anyone can open it without giving them the access to the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing it as following:

- You create a separate storage account + container in it or a separate container in existing storage account & give access to it to developers
- You [mount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts) that container to the Databricks workspace
- You configure clusters/jobs to write logs into mount location (you can enforce it for new objects using the cluster policies).  This will create sub-directories with the cluster name, containing logs of driver & executors + result of execution of init scripts

[image]

- (optional) you can setup retention policy on that container to automatically remove old logs.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reaching out. I ran the job with that config and got the files. However the folder structure looks like this: driver/  eventlog/  executor/  init_scripts/
None of the folders contains Spark History Server files. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, with this you will get just normal spark logs